# Create new instance of the class which is coming as string and update the sets methods

Tags: java, reflection

Im getting class name (string) and the class have few sets method and 
since Its dynamic (I can get any class) I need to use all the sets method and update it with data .
how can I do that ?

To get the class field I'm using the following code

```
className = obj.getClassName();
Class<?> classHandle = Class.forName(className);
```

for example here I need to update firstName and last name

```
public class Person {

private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {

        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setfirstName(String firstName) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
```

or different class here i need to set the salary and the job description

```
public class Job {


  private double salery;
  private String jobDescr;


  public void setSalery(double salery) {
    this.salery = salery;
  }

  public void setJobDescr(String jobDescr) {
    this.jobDescr = jobDescr;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at the API of `Class`. There are all the methods you might want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, What you've done is good. I assume you have a `Map<String, Object>` of the attributes to be set: `attributeMap`.

```
//this is OK
className = obj.getClassName();
Class<?> classHandle = Class.forName(className);

//got the class, create an instance - no-args constructor needed!
Object myObject = classHandle.newInstance();

//iterate through all the methods declared by the class  
for(Method method : classHandle.getMethods()) {
   //check method name
   if(method.getName().matches("set[A-Z].*") 
       //check if it awaits for exactly one parameter
       && method.getParameterTypes().length==1) {

       String attributeName = getAttributeName(method.getName());
       //getAttributeName would chop the "set", and lowercase the first char of the name of the method (left out for clarity)

       //To be extra nice, type checks could be inserted here...
       method.invoke(myObject, attributeMap.get(attributeName));            

   }
}
```

Of course, a lot of exception handling is to be done, this is just a basic idea of what is to be done...

Recommended reading:

- [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)
- [Class.getMethods()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29)
- [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)
- [Method.invoke()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: Thanks for your replay but I get compile error in find and get parametertype - find("set[A-Z]") && method.getParameterTypes ) {
and also in getAttributeName and attribute map 

for find - I getting error The method find(String) is undefined for the type String
for getParameterTypes -  cannot be resolved or is not a field
for The method getAttributeName(String) is undefined for the type...
attribute map -attributeMap cannot be resolved

Comment: Currently i have problem with the find

Comment: I edited the answer a bit. I made some mistakes, find() is not in String - but matches() is... And of course getParameterTypes is not a field, but is a function: getParameterTypes(). But this is not meant to be a full example - you have to provide the getAttributeName() function (look at the comment) and the attributeMap Map<String, Object> for it to work. But if these problems pose obstacles you have a hard time to overcome, I'd advise to start looking at much lower level programming exercises...

Comment: Ok thanks one last quetion ,how can i get the name and the type of the parameter for instance for  setLastName(String lastName) i want to get String lastName .thanks in advance!!!